# Failed to set up map cache HERE MAPS OFFLINE

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

I am using here maps for offline navigation in my iOS application and everything worked perfectly when in separate project, but when I tried to include the maps in my existing app, a "Failed to set up map cache" error occurs.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [NMAMapView class];
  NMAGeoCoordinates * coordinateCenter=[[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc]initWithLatitude:12.878831 longitude:80.095566];
  [self.mapView setGeoCenter:coordinateCenter withAnimation:NMAMapAnimationNone];
  self.mapView.zoomLevel=13.2;
  [[NMAMapLoader sharedMapLoader] setDelegate:self];
  [[NMAMapLoader sharedMapLoader] checkForMapDataUpdate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added proper authentication for ther HERE SDK in your existing application? For example in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [NMAApplicationContext setAppId:@"{YOUR_APP_ID}" 
  appCode:@"{YOUR_APP_CODE}" 
  licenseKey:@"{YOUR_LICENSE_KEY}"];

  return YES;
}
```

Note that credentials are unique to your application's bundle identifier. They cannot be reused across multiple applications.

Source: [Authenticating Applications](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/credentials.html)

Comment: both applications have same bundle identifier @AndrewJC

Comment: i had also tried creating a new license key but no improvement @AndrewJC

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple.html to properly copy the NMAKit and NMABundle into your project? The error you mentioned will happen if the HERE SDK is not able to properly copy resource files from the NMABundle for some reason.